# Set scoped popup form property data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a winforms app that dynamically creates sub form popups in runtime based on runtime data. I would
like each popup to have it's own scope, which I think that I have achieved. Also, I would like to set a "player profile" resolved by the scope, based on the runtime data. This is where I need help.

Each popup form has a profile data property:

```
public partial class PlayerForm : Form
{
    public IPlayerProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

I open the forms using a registered form generator:

```
public TForm GetForm<TForm>(ActiveGame gameInfo) where TForm : PlayerForm
{
    var scope = new Scope(_container);
    var form = scope.GetInstance<TForm>();
    form.GameInfo = gameInfo;

    // set the profile:
    // form.Profile = ...

    form.Closed += (s, e) => scope.Dispose();
    return form;
}
```

The `scope` doesn't have a `GetAllInstances` method. How can I get and set the matching `IPlayerProfile` here? The `gameInfo` contains the type name to find the appropriate profile.

Relevant container config:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = ScopedLifestyle.Flowing;

var registrations = profiles.Select(t => Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(t, container));
container.Collection.Register<IPlayerProfile>(registrations);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Container.GetAllInstances<T>()` is equivalent to `Container.GetInstance<IEnumerable<T>>()` and this holds with `Scope` too that, as you mentioned, misses a `GetAllInstances` method. So you can call this:

```
var profiles = scope.GetInstance<IEnumerable<IPlayerProfile>>();
```

Or you can resolve any other [supported collection type](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#collection-types), such as:

```
var profiles = scope.GetInstance<IReadOnlyCollection<IPlayerProfile>>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Followup question though, if I use your suggestion, I get `"DefaultProfile is registered using the 'Scoped' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of an active (Scoped) scope.`. While if if I use `scope.GetInstance(typeof(DefaultProfile))` for example I don't get the exception. What's the difference?

Comment: That's interesting. Might be a bug. Let me investigate and get back to you.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug. I added [an issue](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/829) that you can follow to track its status. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries at all. Thanks for a great framework and great support as usual

Comment: I pushed [version 5.0.2](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/releases/tag/5.0.2) that fixes this bug.